# Executable file cannot run on Android L

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-5.0-lollipop

It shows an error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.

But it works well on 4.4.

Even I change my Application.mk of NDK like this:

```
APP_PLATFORM:= android-16
APP_ABI := armeabi
```

I push the file to "system/bin" and run, but it still fails.

Does anybody know how can I build the executable file by NDK tool and can run on Android L?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the binary has to be built as PIE. So add the following flag in your Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -pie -fPIE
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -pie -fPIE
```

Comment: These also need to be in the linker flags, not only in the cflags. Also - these should already be added automatically as long as APP_PLATFORM >= android-16 (assuming he's using a recent enough NDK).

Comment: i use the latest NDK r10。

Comment: Did adding the flags work? Probably it is necessary to add LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -pie -fPIE too

Comment: as you said,I add “LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -pie -fPIE” and “LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fPIE -pie” to Application.mk. I push the executable file to "system/bin" and run.But it still fail.

Comment: The flags should be in Android.mk not Application.mk

Answer (score 0):

LOCAL_XXX variables defined in Application.mk are simply ignored.
You must use them inside module definitions that are located within Android.mk files instead.

The alternative is to use APP_CFLAGS and APP_LDFLAGS instead in Application.mk, these will affect all modules compiled by ndk-build.

Comment: yes,you are right.Add to Android.mk and it works.Tks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

yes, I fixed it some weeks ago.

if you are using NDK , maybe you can comment the ,download the latest NDK, I try download the 10C.

```
From 4b673bc0e1f94c06d15ffc1c8ab8feeac4de5170 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
Date: Tue, 28 Oct 2014 14:38:00 +0800
Subject: [PATCH] 1 fPIE 2 APP_ABI enable forcely.

---
 android-ndk-r10c/build/core/build-binary.mk |    6 ++++--
 android-ndk-r10c/ndk-build                  |    5 ++++-
 2 files changed, 8 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)

diff --git a/android-ndk-r10c/build/core/build-binary.mk b/android-ndk-r10c/build/core/build-binary.mk
index 661ca98..59ff54a 100644
--- a/android-ndk-r10c/build/core/build-binary.mk
+++ b/android-ndk-r10c/build/core/build-binary.mk
@@ -206,15 +206,17 @@ else
   LOCAL_CFLAGS += $($(my)FORMAT_STRING_CFLAGS)
 endif

+#LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fPIE
+#LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fPIE -pie
 # enable PIE for executable beyond certain API level, unless "-static"
-ifneq (,$(filter true,$(NDK_APP_PIE) $(TARGET_PIE)))
+#ifneq (,$(filter true,$(NDK_APP_PIE) $(TARGET_PIE)))
   ifeq ($(call module-get-class,$(LOCAL_MODULE)),EXECUTABLE)
     ifeq (,$(filter -static,$(TARGET_LDFLAGS) $(LOCAL_LDFLAGS) $(NDK_APP_LDFLAGS)))
       LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fPIE
       LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fPIE -pie
     endif
   endif
-endif
+#endif

 #
 # The original Android build system allows you to use the .arm prefix
diff --git a/android-ndk-r10c/ndk-build b/android-ndk-r10c/ndk-build
index 62d6dc8..e3663da 100755
--- a/android-ndk-r10c/ndk-build
+++ b/android-ndk-r10c/ndk-build
@@ -243,7 +243,8 @@ if [ "$OSTYPE" = "cygwin" ] ; then
     log "Cygwin-compatible GNU make detected"
 fi

-if [ "$NDK_ANALYZE" = 1 ]; then
+if [ "$NDK_ANALYZE" != 1 ]; then
+echo "ndk analysis if"
     . $PROGDIR/build/tools/dev-defaults.sh  # for DEFAULT_LLVM_VERSION

     # Find perl.  If HOST_PERL is defined, check that it points to a valid file
@@ -311,6 +312,7 @@ if [ "$NDK_ANALYZE" = 1 ]; then
     }

     APP_ABIS=`get_build_var APP_ABI`
+    echo "app abis: ${APP_ABIS}"
     for ABI in $APP_ABIS; do
         TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX=`get_build_var_for_abi TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX $ABI`
         PERL5LIB="$HOST_PERL_LIB" "$HOST_PERL" $PROGDIR/prebuilt/common/scan-build/scan-build \
@@ -321,6 +323,7 @@ if [ "$NDK_ANALYZE" = 1 ]; then
             $GNUMAKE -f $PROGDIR/build/core/build-local.mk "$@" APP_ABI=$ABI
     done
 else
+    echo  "ndk analysis else"
     $GNUMAKE -f $PROGDIR/build/core/build-local.mk "$@"
 fi

-- 
1.7.9.5
```

After you compiled , get your binary so library or executable file. You may use the readelf -all to check 
PIE is work or not by check the HEAD of elf. http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2008/06/position-independent-executables.html .